# SimpleCursorAdapter returns empty data

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

When I am trying to put data from Database to ListView via SimpleCursorAdapter, the rows of the ListView are shown but they are empty.

Like:

[***_*__*_*__*_*____**]

[***_*__*_*__*_*____**]

[***_*__*_*__*_*____**]

Instead of:

[TEXT]

[TEXT]

[TEXT]

My code:

```
    db = provider.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {"_id", "Title"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(NotificationsProvider.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    Log.d(TAG, "COUNT: "+cursor.getCount());
    String[] clm = {"Title"};
    int[] to = {android.R.id.list};
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor, clm, to, 0);

    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply using the wrong id, try:

```
int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
```

(You can check out [`simple_list_item_1.xml`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) yourself to verify the appropriate id.)